# looping many excels into seperate dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dataframe

I am relatively new to Python 3 and i need help on looping in 4 excel spreedsheets as seperate df. i can do this by manually typing in pd.read_excel(filepath, index_col=0) for each of the 4 filepaths but i was looking for a robust way to simply loop in all my filepaths that i have and create a df per filepath (excel spreedsheet). can anyone help me? thanks

```
filepath = '/Users/User/Desktop/Tax\Year.xlsx'
filepath2 = '/Users/User/Desktop/Tax\Year2.xlsx'
filepath3 = '/Users/User/Desktop/Tax\Year3.xlsx'
filepath4 = '/Users/User/Desktop/Tax\Year4.xlsx'  

df = pd.read_excel(filepath, index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel(filepath2, index_col=0)
df3 = pd.read_excel(filepath3, index_col=0)
df4 = pd.read_excel(filepath4, index_col=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put a '1' on the first filepath.

```
dict_of_dfs = {}
for n in range(1,5):
    filepath = '/Users/User/Desktop/Tax/Year' + str(n) + '.xlsx'
    df = pd.read_excel(filepath, index_col=0)
    dict_of_dfs[n] = df

# retrieve your dfs...
df1 = dict_of_dfs[1]
df2 = dict_of_dfs[2]
# etc...
```

Further to OPs question below. Use walk from os library to be able to load filenames from a directory and then walk through them in a list

```
from os import walk
directory = '/Users/User/Desktop/Tax/Year'

f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(directory):
    f.extend(filenames)
    break
```

Then you can access your filenames through a for loop:

```
for n in f: 
    filepath = '/Users/User/Desktop/Tax/Year' + n
    df = pd.read_excel(filepath, index_col=0)
    dict_of_dfs[n] = df
```

Comment: what about if the filepaths are completely different. i would like to use the code for other filepaths which have different folder names etc. is there any way?